# how to check if the textbox is in focus in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox, I want to check if it has focus (User clicks on textbox) in plain javascript . How can I do that in javascript not JQuery ?

Comment: does `document.activeElement` work?

Comment: yup, he but needed to google :/